# Div background-image isn't showing

Tags: html, css, w3c

I wanted to put a background image inside the div "pageIntro". I've tried setting the background color to transparent, checked the image file path numerous times (it is certainly correct as when I click it in my code using vsCode it pops the correct image).

Note: putting a background color works fine

[*screensnip of the div with NO background color. Background-image is set to '/img/home/flower-cup.jpg'.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ruy.png)

[*screensnip of the div with GOLD background color. Background-image is still set to '/img/home/flower-cup.jpg'.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMlB8.png)

Here's the CSS of the div and all the elements inside it:

```
div.pageIntro {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('/img/home/flower-cup.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 001;
    text-align: center;
}

.introDiv {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    text-align: center;
    z-index: 002;

}

.introText {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "eczar";
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 50px;
    z-index: 002;
}

.subIntroButton {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5%;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    border-width: 2px;

    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class='pageIntro'>
    <div class="introDiv">
            <p class='introText'> You deserve it. </p>
            <a href="menu.html" style="text-decoration : none">
                <div class='subIntroButton'> check treats </div>
            </a>
    </div>
    <span class="blinking" href="javascript:"><a href="javascript:"><img src="img/arrow-down.png" style="position: relative; bottom: 12%; width: 40px"></span></div></a>
</div>
```

**Thank you very much :)**

UPDATE:
[Here's what it looks like when putting the background-image on BOTH inner and outer div. Unfortunately, it only works on the inner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fxiD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi As I can see your relative path.

if the `image` forlder is in same path of your `html`

What i can see error in your `HTML`. Which is `span` is not properly closed with `a` and `img` tag.

```
<div class='pageIntro'>
    <div class="introDiv">
            <p class='introText'> You deserve it. </p>
            <a href="menu.html" style="text-decoration : none">
                <div class='subIntroButton'> check treats </div>
            </a>
    </div>
    <span class="blinking" href="javascript:"><a href="javascript:"><img src="img/arrow-down.png" style="position: relative; bottom: 12%; width: 40px"/></a></span>
</div>
```

you can use `.`

```
div.pageIntro {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('./img/home/flower-cup.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 001;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or if its `one above` your path you can use `..`

```
div.pageIntro {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('../img/home/flower-cup.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 001;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have created one [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64jp837e/)

Comment: I feel that the path is correctly stated. It is working when I change the inner div's (.introDiv) background image with the same url. It doesn't work on the outer div.

Comment: I have updted my answer.

Comment: I tried changing that line into this:
<span class="blinking" href="javascript:"><a href="javascript:"><img src="img/arrow-down.png" style="position: relative; bottom: 12%; width: 40px"></a></span>
However it doesn't seem to make the bg appear

Comment: Muchas gracias. I figured I need to remove the slash before 'img/home/flower-cup.jpg'

Comment: Oh yeahh. I have mentioned that you haven't closed `a` and `img` tag properly. cheers

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with your ***Image Relative Path*** i just tried you code with an online image path its working fine.

```css
div.pageIntro {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 001;
    text-align: center;
}

.introDiv {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    text-align: center;
    z-index: 002;

}

.introText {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "eczar";
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 50px;
    z-index: 002;
}

.subIntroButton {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5%;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    border-width: 2px;

    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='pageIntro'>
    <div class="introDiv">
            <p class='introText'> You deserve it. </p>
            <a href="menu.html" style="text-decoration : none">
                <div class='subIntroButton'> check treats </div>
            </a>
    </div>
    <span class="blinking" href="javascript:"><a href="javascript:"><img src="img/arrow-down.png" style="position: relative; bottom: 12%; width: 40px"></span></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that the image path is correctly stated. It is working when I change the inner div's  background-image with the same url as the outer one. However, it doesn't work on the outer. I added a screensnip of it below my question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I removed the slash before img/home/flower-cup.jpg. The img folder is in the same as the current html file.

Comment: exactly.... thats why i mentioned the issue... `relative path`